# Spring Batch/ Integration: Best Practice Q to retrieve .csv file from web and process

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

What do you consider a best practice to retrieve and process a .csv file from a URL?

1) Would I somehow override the Spring Batch FlatFileItemReader to read the file from the URL?  (if so, can you give guidance as to what I would override?)

== OR ==

2) Would I use a Spring Integration step to retrieve the .csv file from the URL and pass it into a Spring Batch process? From there, I would have to figure out how to pass a MemoryStream to the source of the FlatFileItemReader.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have concerns about streaming interruptions while importing file from remote URL download it in local using a tasklet (you may use Integration and channels, but I'm unfamiliar with that) and, after, read/process/write normally using a FlatFileItemReader from local file

Comment: Hi, I wonder if you aware(yet) to any SpringIntegration adapter to download a file via tasklet?